# STL containers vs Structs

Tags: c++, struct, stl

I would like to know what is better to use and why:

Before I used to create types with STL Containers, but recently I've found that APIs use struct like types, which I think is due to the use of C instead of C++, but I want to know what is best in terms of performance and memory.

Before:

```
typedef std::tuple<std::string, int, int, bool> SomeType;
```

Now:

```
typedef struct tagSomeType { std::string sVar; int iVar, iVar2; bool bVar; } SomeType;
```

Thank you

[EDIT] I put this example of tuple to make it visible, but for example

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> iCoord; /* VS */ struct iCoord{int x, y;};
```

Seems that the only diference is that struct has more readability than STL Container

Comment: It really depends, on use-cases, on design, on availability of e.g. `std::tuple` (it is a C++11 type after all), and more.

Comment: Also remember that in C++ you don't need to use `typedef` for structures or  classes. The structure or class tag name is a type name.

Comment: Structs are far more expressive and easier to understand. Tuples are very useful in template scaffolding but not very friendly in the `API`.

Comment: Your question appears to be about `struct`and `tuple` not `STL` containers.

Comment: `std::pair` is not an `STL` container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no significant difference in memory usage and performance. So the main criterion should be readability.

One difference is that in a `struct`, each element has a name, which is not the case for `tuple`s. Especially if you have more that 2 or 3 elements, this can make structs more readable.

By the way, your struct declaration is C style. In C++ you can write it like this:

```
struct SomeType { std::string sVar; int iVar, iVar2; bool bVar; };
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no unique answer to this question and it depends on your situation. My own opinion is that if you have more than two variables you should use struct, unless you have a strong reason not to. In struct you can give names to your variables, so that you don't have to memorize that number 1 is this and number 2 is that.